# Looking for a Country name

Tags: riddle, geography

**Name the country**

The Humulus lupulus is our water.

The heart is our location.

and we are surrounded by the Shakespeare sea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are in:

> Czech Republic

First clue:

> Czech Republic has the highest beer consumption per capita in the world.

Second clue:

> Czech Republic is sometimes called the Heart of Europe

Third clue (credit to [M Oehm](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9860/m-oehm) for the find):

> The third clue is a reference to a painting and a poem of the name *Bohemia Lies by the Sea*, the poem was inspired by Shakespeare's play, *The Winter's Tale*, scene III, "Bohemia. A Desert Country near the Sea."

Comment: (Perhaps there is a [better explanation](http://www.paintersandpoets.com/2012/07/normal-0-false-false-false-en-us-ja-x.html) for the third line.)

Comment: I think there is, still working on it.

Comment: Correct! The third clue belongs to @MOehm.

Comment: Nice find @MOehm, I’ll update my third clue answer crediting you and your find.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Please also change typo to Czech Republic or Czechia.

Comment: I have Czeched my spelling.